# How to remote-access a running program in linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, vnc, remote, remote-access

I left a program (netbeans) running on a remote computer and I'd like to save the session 
(I know, I know |-( ), and exit, so I can work at my current location. I do have access to that computer via ssh and I can see the program running when I type `ps -u myusername`. But it seems I'd have to enter the program somehow or "pipe" the remote desktop to the local.
Is that possible?
All questions I found in that direction were related to starting a new program with a GUI remotely with `ssh -X`, but that doesn't seem to help for this situation.
Thanks already!

**Edit:**
Thanks to [fede.evol](https://superuser.com/users/277008/fede-evol) I figured out, that the right thing to use is vncviewer/vncserver (*x11vnc* isn't installed on the remote computer, but *Tight VNC 1.3.10* is).
However, my problem seems to involve an additional difficulty, because I don't connect directly to the remote computer (say, `mycomp.server.com`) but via another computer (say `sshhost.server.com`). Usually (that is using `ssh -X` to do sth), I first connect to `sshhost` and from there to `mycomp` which works ok.
I managed to set up a vncviewer (`ssvnc`) at my present location, and I also managed to obtain a remote desktop on `sshhost.server.com` by

`ssvnc myusername@sshhost.server.com:1`

(I started a new X-display :1 on `sshhost` by typing `vncserver` and set the password with `vncpasswd` because I don't have access to display :0 on `sshhost`, I think) My plan was to access the desktop of `mycomp` via this vnc-connection to `sshhost` analogously to how I it do when ssh-connecting (that is `ssh -X myusername@sshhost.server.com` and then `ssh -X mycomp`).
First problem: Typing on `sshhost`, I can't just say:

`vncviewer mycomp:0`

because I get `Couldn't convert 'mycomp' to host address`.
So I pinged `mycomp` to obtain its IP and used that instead of `mycomp` in the last command. But it doesn't work. I get:

`vncviewer: ConnectToTcpAddr: connect: Connection timed out
Unable to connect to VNC server`

So, I'm stuck here...

Answer (score 0):

If it is already up and running I'd suggest you to export the current X display via VNC and then use VNC to access it. You can do this with [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) which is available with many distributions nowadays.

You should start the program with something like:

> x11vnc -display :0